# How to detected forbidden letters in a variable that comes from html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

acutally my english is not good but i want to detect forbidden letters in a variable that comes from html input but its not working.
My code:

```js
nextBtnFirst.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Validating the required Fields//
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname_id").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname_id").value;
  var letters = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/";
  if(fname =="" || lname=="") {
    updateError("First name and Last name is required!");
  } else {
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
    bullet[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressCheck[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    progressText[current - 1].classList.add("active");
    current += 1;
  } 
});
```

What i have tried but didnt work:

```js
if(fname.includes("!")) { 
  updateError("Dont use forbidden Characters!"); 
}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

Comment: @JaredSmith but i want to check in javascript and not in html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: @Temal the thing is that if you try to determine if it's not forbidden FROM the client side.. that's a vulnerability - as in the client can just set things on their side so that it sends the forbidden characters anyway

Comment: @JaredSmith ok i will try match() and will tell you the result

Comment: I can think in 100000 names in english and/or spanish that have "forbidden letters". You should think in change your regular expression

Comment: `<input id="foo" pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$" />` then `const inputTextIsValid = document.getElementById('foo').matches(':invalid')`

Comment: ok, so how to check if fname ONLY contains ABC letters? (A-Z)

Comment: @Temal that's another question. In any case I suggest you again don't do that check, you can easily search here in S.O. a regular expression for names.

Comment: Just to name one thing, your regex does not allow spaces or periods, e.g. 'St. Johns'

Comment: @JaredSmith and don't forget about our little Bobby O'Tables

Answer (score -1):

Change
`var fname = document.getElementById("fname_id").value;` to this
`var fname = document.getElementById("fname_id").innerText;`

`HTMLElement` object has no `value` property.

Comment: still dont work

Comment: Does the `fname` variable return any value? Because using `value` property returns `undefined` for me here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buon8753/)

Comment: "HTMLElement object has no value property." there are a number of HTMLElements with value properties, most notably `input`s and `select`s. Since OP did not post HTML, why do you assume that is the issue?